# extract the lines from file with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, grep

Here is my file content which is output of pflogsumm

```
Host/Domain Summary: Messages Received 
---------------------------------------
 msg cnt   bytes   host/domain
 -------- -------  -----------
    415     5416k  abc.com
     13    19072   xyz.localdomain

Senders by message count
------------------------
    415   alert@example.com
     13   root@jelly.localdomain

Recipients by message count
---------------------------
    506   alert@apple.com            <= Extract from here to ...
     70   info@pafpro.org.us
     ..
     ...
     19   gems@gmail.com
     17   info@aol.com
     13   hemdem@gmail.com           <= Extract ends here

Senders by message size
-----------------------
   5416k  alert@google.com
...
 ...
```

The output seems to have the information feilds separated by "title" and a "new line". For example `Recipients by message count ...<contents of interest> ... NewLine`
I tried with below sed expression but it returns all lines after matching the string `"Recipients by message count"`

`sed -nr '/.*Recipients by message count/,/\n/ p'`

Desired output: All emails under `"Recipients by message count"`

Comment: its not clear, whats the desired output !!! please be precise.

Comment: updated the post for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '/Recipients by message count/{p=1}!$0{p=0}p' input_file
```

Will print the *Recipients by message count* block

Breakdown:

```
/Recipients by message count/ {p=1} # When /pattern/ is matched set p = 1
!$0 {p=0}                           # When input line is empty set p = 0
p                                   # Print line if p is true, short for:
                                    # p { print $0 }
```

Comment: your solution works like a charm , would you kindly tell us what `{p=1}!$0{p=0}p'` does here. Thank you

Comment: @satch_boogie Updated with breakdown, please let me know it you understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n '/Recipients by message count/,/^\s*$/ p' data | sed -n '1!{2!{$!p}}'
    506   alert@apple.com            <= Extracter from here to ...
     70   info@pafpro.org.us
     ..
     ...
     19   gems@gmail.com
     17   info@aol.com
     13   hemdem@gmail.com           <= Extract ends here
```

Comment: This `sed -n '1!{2!{$!p}}'` can be shortened to `sed -n '3,$p'`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    findthis = "Recipients by message count"

    with open("tst.dat") as f:
      while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line: break

        if not findthis in line:
          continue
        line = f.readline()

        while True:
          line = f.readline()
          if not line: break
          line = line.rstrip()     ## get rid of whitespace
          if line == "":           ## empty line
            break
          print(line)
```

If the file is big or you have wildcard searches, use the regular expression library.

Answer (score 1):

Below script :

```
sed -n '/Recipients/{n;n;:loop;/^$/!{p;n;b loop};q}' filename
```

will do the job for you.

**Note :** If the pattern of interest is at the very end, you require a trailing blank line.

Answer (score 0):

An awk command, for the lines between "Recipients" and "Senders", if the line starts with a space, print it.

```
[name@server ~]$ awk '/^Recipients/,/^Senders/ { if ($0~/^ /) print }' input.txt
    506   alert@apple.com            <= Extracter from here to ...
     70   info@pafpro.org.us
     ..
     ...
     19   gems@gmail.com
     17   info@aol.com
     13   hemdem@gmail.com           <= Extract ends here
```

Answer (score 0):

Another sed one liner :

```
 sed '/Recipients by message count/,/^$/!d;//{N;d};' file
```